# How to bind FlowDocument sub elements to data in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to create text that is bound to my data (`Paragraph`, `ListItem`, `Run`):

- A `ListItem` that appears only if a certain Boolean property is true (think of a warning in product description that only shows for dangerous items)
- Several statements in a text paragraph that are from a `List<String>` in my data
- Several `Paragraph`s in a `FlowDocument` that are from a `List<String>` in my data

I did not find a way to bind these types of elements (that render as a flow of text). Seems as if only elements that render as a grid, or form elements such as buttons and textboxes, are boundable.

**Or am I missing something here?**

Here is what I tried:

- I can bind a Run to a specific property: `<Run x:Name="prescriptionMedicine" Text="{Binding Field1, Mode=OneWay}" />`, but I cannot put `<Run ... />` within a container that supports `ItemsSource` (such as `<ItemsControl ... ItemsSource="{Binding List1, Mode=OneWay}">`) to provide a varying number of `Run`s
- I tried using `ItemTemplate`such as in the code below, but the ItemsTemplate will not accept `Paragraph` (using `WrapPanel` in the example below, but this is not what I want).

  ```
  <ItemsControl ... ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding List1}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <WrapPanel/>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  </ItemsControl>
  ```
- Within the template, I can only use `Run` if it is within a `TextBox` (or `Grid`, etc). This does not end up rendered as I want - a free flow of text that happens to be built from repeating parts.